# Execute command as user and not su

Tags: mount, sudo

Currently my computer allows me to mount network drives only with sudo, which is a huge pain because then I only have read access to the drives as long as I don't sudo open/edit/delete/add files on them.

I would simply like to mount the drives without using sudo, which currently I can't:

> ```
> $mount -t cifs -o username=MY-USERNAME,domain=dom //NETWORK-DRIVE-ADDRESS ~/MOUNT-POINT
> mount.cifs: permission denied
> ```

I don't see why I shouldn't be able to execute mount as a regular user. Is there a way to change my system to allow for this?

I'm on Manjaro Linux 4.14.235-1-MANJARO

Comment: Read `man sudo sudoers`. Since `mount`ing affects the whole system, you must be `root` (UID 0) to do it.

Comment: @waltinator read `man mount` ;-).

Comment: @waltinator for what I hope is the last time: either answer the question, or vote your conscience and walk away. Stop leaving "read `man foo`" comments. They are unhelpful, condescending and not welcome.

Comment: @waltinator The man page says that in order to mount it without sudo, the file system needs to be in the fstab table, which in my case it is, and I'm still getting the same error.